# How to stop vibrating on new Mail using iOS 7?

Tags: mail.app, ios

Whenever I get a new message in my mail, my phone vibrates. How do I turn off this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do that is to go into "Sounds" in Settings and pick "None" as the sound for Mail. This is bad because without Sound there will be no indication of new email when the phone is locked. Hope that in a future iOS release, this option will be added.

Comment: Is it possible to have a sound without vibrate. See answer by @JW_

Answer (score 11):

Go to; Sounds -> New Mail -> Vibration (at the top) -> Select "None" (in the bottom)

Answer (score 2):

you can also do custom vibration, which I found was great. under sounds --> new mail--> vibration-->custom--> create new vibration. Just tap it gently once only and remove our finger. Hit stop and then save.

I found it this was much better than using any of the custom tones. Esp if you are your using your iphone for work and when its on the desk, it vibrates everytime you get an emai and the whole office knows.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Go to Notification Centre > Mail. Then choose the account you want.

Then choose alert sound > vibration.

There is a 'none' option at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

right above your volume keys on the left side of your phone, you will see a knob.. make sure you dont see the orange mark. if your sounds setting is set on vibrate when silent and you see the orange mark on the knob above the volume knobs or keys your phone will vibrate when you receive new mail. left side meaning on the left of your phone not on the screen.

try if that works.